# Access function member using it address

Tags: c

Trying to access/print function member using following snippet

```
void func()
{
        int i=4;
}

int *k = func + 4;

int main()
{
        printf("%x\n", func);
        printf("%x\n", k);
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)k);
        return 0;
}
```

and looking to get value of i through last printf statement but wondering if it is possible this way ?

output of program is:

```
400526
40052a
83641799
```

Comment: No, that is impossible. The lifetime of such a local variable is bound to the function call, so it no longer exists outside of a call

Comment: @UnholySheep: more significantly, ```func``` is never called, so ```i``` never exists in the first place. This is all kinds of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no, it's not possible at all to do in any reliable way.

And this idea does not make sense either. The variable `i` will typically not be exist nearby the function code. Also, it will typically be created at different places on different calls.

However, something that's possible is this:

```
int *func()
{
    static int i=4;
    return &i;
}

int *k;

int main()
{
    k = func();
```

That's perfectly valid, even if the usefulness could be discussed.

But you will never be able to access it via an offset to the function pointer. At least not in a legal way.